# Using DialogFragment in android

Tags: android, fragment, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to launch a DialogFragment

**What i am trying to do**::

- I have disabled GPS manually before starting the application
- I am checking if the GPS is switched off
- If it is switched off, I am popping up a dialog which asks a
  permission to take to settings page

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if ( !locationManager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
            showDialog();
        }
    }

    public void showDialog(){
        //GPS-Dialog
        GpsEnablingDialog gpsAlert;
        try {
            gpsAlert = new GpsEnablingDialog();
            gpsAlert.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "GpsAlert_Tag");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("My-Log-Msg",e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

**GpsEnablingDialog.java**

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GpsEnablingDialog extends DialogFragment {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        builder.setMessage("GPS is not Enabled \n Enable GPS ?");
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Enable the GPS and restart the application", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Go to Settings page
                //startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
            }
        });

        Dialog dialog=builder.create();
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

---

**Problem I am facing**::

In MainActivity for the line

```
gpsAlert = new GpsEnablingDialog();
```

*I am getting error as shown below*:: (LOG)

```
04-23 12:02:04.234: D/My-Log-Msg(775): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-23 12:02:05.063: W/System.err(775): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-23 12:02:05.125: W/System.err(775):  at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:142)
04-23 12:02:05.144: W/System.err(775):  at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:359)
04-23 12:02:05.164: W/System.err(775):  at com.example.enablegpsfromsettingpagewhenappstarts.GpsEnablingDialog.<init>(GpsEnablingDialog.java:13)
04-23 12:02:05.174: W/System.err(775):  at com.example.enablegpsfromsettingpagewhenappstarts.MainActivity.showDialog(MainActivity.java:29)
04-23 12:02:05.184: W/System.err(775):  at com.example.enablegpsfromsettingpagewhenappstarts.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
04-23 12:02:05.193: W/System.err(775):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-23 12:02:05.215: W/System.err(775):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-23 12:02:05.224: W/System.err(775):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
04-23 12:02:05.234: W/System.err(775):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
04-23 12:02:05.254: W/System.err(775):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
04-23 12:02:05.263: W/System.err(775):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
04-23 12:02:05.274: W/System.err(775):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-23 12:02:05.284: W/System.err(775):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-23 12:02:05.304: W/System.err(775):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
04-23 12:02:05.304: W/System.err(775):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 12:02:05.324: W/System.err(775):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-23 12:02:05.334: W/System.err(775):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-23 12:02:05.344: W/System.err(775):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-23 12:02:05.354: W/System.err(775):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

**MyQuestion**::
What mistake i am doing and how to resolve this ?

Thanks .... !

Comment: getActivity returns null before onAttach, that's your mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
```

Is causing `NullPointerException`

Move it to `onCreateDialog`.

`getActivity()` returns null in your case. You initialized alert dialog outside of `onCreateDialog`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#Lifecycle

There also an example of `AlertDialog` in the docs

Your stacktraces indicates that alertdialog initialization fails

```
04-23 12:02:05.144: W/System.err(775):  at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:359)
04-23 12:02:05.164: W/System.err(775):  at com.example.enablegpsfromsettingpagewhenappstarts.GpsEnablingDialog.<init>(GpsEnablingDialog.java:13)
```

`getActivity()`

```
public final Activity getActivity ()

Added in API level 11
Return the Activity this fragment is currently associated with
```

Comment: Could you give him a bit more of context about what's going on?

Comment: @Raghunandan .... Thanks for clear explanation ..... So it was returning null because Dialog fragment lifecycle has not been started and ..... before that i was trying to get the context ... so context will be availabe after the lifecycle of the Dialog starts .... Am i clear with my understanding

Comment: @Casper yes getActivity() returns null and since context was null your initialization failes

Answer (score 0):

create constructor and call this

```
Context mContext;
public GpsEnablingDialog() {
    mContext = getActivity();
}

new GpsEnablingDialog().show(getFragmentManager(), "MyDialog");
```

Comment: getActivity returns null before onAttach

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from here

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
```

We dont know if the getActivity() is null in there;

**solution:**

pass the context to ur contructor

```
   //in main Activity
   gpsAlert = new GpsEnablingDialog(this)
   //in dialog fragment
   public GpsEnablingDialog (Context context)
   {
      builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(context);     
   }
```